# What is this black spider, with round body, long front legs found in Belgium?

Tags: bug-identification, spider

While doing some work in our basement I saw a spider and its shape and colour is unlike anything I've seen around here. I live in the northern part of Belgium.

The spider is black, almost shiny and as far as I can tell bears no marks on their thick, round body. The front legs arch up. It kind of reminds me of a (Black) Widow. The spider is not very large, but I didn't dare getting any closer to measure.

The spider was in its web, near a vent. It could get drafty up there I assume, and there's some natural light from outside, at the other end of the vent.

You can see the spider in the picture below, alongside electrical wiring. Hopefully that gives an indication of its size.

[image: nope]

Based on some Googling, I'm assuming this is a [False Widow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steatoda_grossa) and hence not dangerous, but I would appreciate some second opinion on this.

Comment: Do you have an image from the back of it?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm unable to get a good different angle